# Using timer to display and hide object in Processing

Tags: timer, processing, show-hide

I'm a beginner program and trying to create a "Simon" memory game using Processing. I'm currently using a timer to display a new object every second. However, I cannot determine how to make the object disappear shortly after it is displayed (e.g., half a second after it appears). I've tried creating a second timer object that redraws the background after a certain amount of time, but it's just not working. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```java
int j = 0;
void draw() {
if (displayTimer.isFinished()){
  hideTimer.start();
  if(hideTimer.isFinished()){
    drawBackground();
  }
      if (nomisSequence[j] == color(255, 0, 0)) {
        drawBackground();
        button1.display();
      }
      else if (nomisSequence[j] == color(0, 255, 0)) {
        drawBackground();
        button2.display();
      }
      else if (nomisSequence[j] == color(0, 0, 255)) {
        drawBackground();  
        button3.display();
        } 
      else if (nomisSequence[j] == color(255, 255, 0)) {
        drawBackground();
        button4.display();
      }

      if(hideTimer.isFinished()){
        drawBackground();
      }

      j++;
      displayTimer.start();
      hideTimer.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: What are `displayTimer` and `hideTimer`? What exactly do you mean when you say it's not working?

Comment: displayTimer and hideTimer are objects I created using a "Timer" class.

Comment: I have an array of colors (red blue green and yellow), and if there happen to be two "reds" in a row i.e., [1] = color(255,0,0) and [2] = color(255,0,0), the application displays one red box on top of the other, rather than making the first box disappear first (i.e., it makes it seem as if the red box was displayed for a prolonged period of time).

Comment: What `Timer` class? Have you tried the approach I outlined in my answer?

Comment: I have, and I'm not sure how to get it to work. I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `timer` objects you're using, but you don't need them. Processing has a handy `millis()` function that you can use.

Just record the start time of any event you want to time, and then check whether that start time plus a duration is less than the current time.

Something like this:

```java
int startMillis;
int duration = 1000;

void draw() {
  background(0);
  if (mousePressed) {
    startMillis = millis();
  }

  if (millis() < startMillis + duration) {
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: In the timer class, I use a boolean that checks if the timer is done (sorry, I cannot figure out how to post this as code):  
    
      'void start(){
        savedTime = millis();
      }
  
      boolean isFinished(){
        int passedTime = millis() - savedTime;
        if(passedTime > totalTime){
          return true;
        }
        else{
          return false;
        }

Comment: inline code use backtics `\`` not single quotes `'`